# Batch rename files using correspondent values

Tags: windows-7, batch, batch-rename

I have a folder full of files, with names composed of 7 digits number. For each of these numbers, I have a correspondent name, saved in an excel file, separated into two columns. Usually, I check line by line and rename file by file, but since the numbers are correspondent, is there a way for me to mass rename the files, using their correspondent values in the table? If needed I can save the table in a txt file separated by tabulation.

Comment: You should be able to do this but I'd say show an example of the exported data in csv format and show an example of the file names or whatever that correlate to the data from the csv file and then show a before and after example to make it super clear what you are trying to accomplish. You may be able to do with a batch file easily but your detail needs clarified a little more for someone like me to help with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I normally do is use Excel's (or LibreOffice's) `CONCAT` function to generate valid commands (along the line of `REN "numberedfile" "newfilename"`), then I copy-paste this column into a text file and rename it to `.bat` and execute it.

Basically I move the harder work of fiddling filenames in `cmd` to the easier work of fiddling them in Excel.

Comment: Interesting idea. I'll try it later.